# Http only cookie doesn't work with rewtrites in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, proxy, fetch

There is an API, which sets an httpOnly cookie on a specific domain (domain B) when accessed. My website's domain is A, and I am using a proxy in Next. When making requests to the server on domain B through the proxy (rewrites in next.js), the httpOnly cookie should be sent, but it does not happen because the request is coming from domain A.

next.config.js

```
    async rewrites() {
    return [

{
        source: '/api/authorization/sign-in', // request from domain A
        destination: `${process.env.WEB_API_BASEURL}/authorization/sign-in`, // set http only cookie on domain B
      },
      {
        source: '/api/authorization/refresh', // request from domain A
        destination: `${process.env.WEB_API_BASEURL}/authorization/refresh`, // doesn't sent http only cookie from domain B
      },
            {
        source: '/api/authorization/userinfo',
        destination: `${process.env.WEB_API_BASEURL}/authorization/userinfo`,
      },
    ]
  },
```

Without proxy everything works fine, but I need use proxy